Where is the filter for my washing machine?
I've got a Candy integrated washing drying machine. If I unscrew the filter at the bottom of the machine, only the cap comes off and I don't seem to be able to remove anything else. I'm attaching a few photos. Any idea?
Manual just says to unscrew the filter and clean it.


The filter should be that black part.   The white part in your hand should be attached to it via those clips on the inside of the cap.
I'd try to (gently) pull the filter out with some needlenose pliers.   Once out, you should see if it will clip back together with the cap (or if some part of the clip is broken).
The Candy website has some photos of the filter as a complete part:  https://www.candy-spares.co.uk/washing/washing-machine/drain-pump-filter/product.pl?pid=1468096&path=1056916,1056919

Thanks, do you think it can be pulled as opposed to unscrew? I tried unscrewing with some pliers but no luck. Haven't tried pulling though..

Yup, turned out that I just needed to pull it with brute force
